# how should i match Jlink edu device output with a board input

Tags: segger-jlink

Hello i am trying to interface a board with J-ling EDU Segger debugger shown in the attached photo.
The board has 8pin connection but the jlink device has 20 pin connection.
I have tried to look in the manual bellow to find out what each output pin one that device represents
https://www.segger.com/downloads/jlink/UM08001
i have attached a photo of the schematics of the board connection.
how do i connect between the board and the JLINK EDU device?
Thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: On https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/technology/interface-description/ there is a description of the pinout of the j-link.

Comment: Hello Steve  on my board i have the 8pin connection where each pin is described as followes:
VSS GND RST TX DIO CLK SWO RX but on the jlink device in the link you advised
i have
Vtref  nTRST TDI TMS  TCK  RTCK  TDO RESET DBGRQ 5V-suplly NC GND

Where should i connect DIO SWO RX TX CLK to the JLINK device they dont have the same name?
Thanks

Comment: If you scroll a bit further down on the link (to https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/technology/interface-description/#swd-and-swo-also-called-swv-compatibility) it shows the _SWD and SWO (also called SWV) Compatibility_ pinout. Not sure about the TX and RX connections though. I've never used those for jtag connections.

Comment: Hello Steve, on my Jlink device what is the pin order, i cant see on the actual device .
there is the bulge but its not helping much
Thanks

Comment: The bulge on the connector should be sufficient to determine the pinout of the segger. I haven't got one around me right now, but you can always measure between pin 19 and 20 (which ought to give 5v) with the segger plugged into USB. Between pin 1 and 2 there should not be 5v.